# Tabs go to top if i set customView of ActionBar on Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view, android-tabs

I add tabs and viewpager to my project.

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Everything is perfect until i set custom view of actionBar:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
....
actionBar.setCustomView(vv,layoutParams);
```

Perfect: ActionBar itself at the top and tabs are below the actionBar.

When i set the custom view, tabs change place and goes to top and actionBar goes to below of tabs.

What am i doing wrong? I want the actionbar stay always at the top of the screen.

Comment: Just another thought: if you want the tabs to *always* sit below the `ActionBar` (and not have them as part of it on the same 'line'), you could use a [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/). More specifically, have a look at including a `TabPageIndicator` in your activity's layout, which should yield pretty much the same visual result as the tabs navigation mode.

Comment: Eventhough this directly does not answer my question (as it is not accepted as a bug by Google), it solved my problem! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear the alternative worked out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can vote for this bug on Android code:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36191

There are some tricks to avoid this that you can read here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/327

But the official Google answer is

> This is a working as intended UX decision.
>   (Roman Nurik).

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as it seems like this is a very bad and wrong Google decision and this can not be fixed. I tried the tricks but spaces appear around customView which can not be accepted.